# What is the BigO of linear regression?

Tags: big-o, linear-regression, blas, gsl

How large a system is it reasonable to attempt to do a linear regression on?

Specifically: I have a system with ~300K sample points and ~1200 linear terms. Is this computationally feasible?

Comment: Which algorithm? Least squares?

Comment: Yes, Least squares. I was unaware there was any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can express this as a matrix equation:

[image]

where the matrix [image] is 300K rows and 1200 columns, the coefficient vector [image] is 1200x1, and the RHS vector [image] is 1200x1.

If you multiply both sides by the transpose of the matrix [image], you have a system of equations for the unknowns that's 1200x1200.  You can use LU decomposition or any other algorithm you like to solve for the coefficients.  (This is what least squares is doing.)

So the Big-O behavior is something like O(m*m*n), where m = 300K and n = 1200.  You'd account for the transpose, the matrix multiplication, the LU decomposition, and the forward-back substitution to get the coefficients.

Comment: So, if I'm reading that correctly (and IIRC), generating the A will be O(n*m)~=O(m^2) (in my case `n/m=C`) and the multiplication will be O(n*n*m)~=O(n^3) and the inversion will be O(n^3) Now just to figure out the constant term.

Answer (score 10):

The linear regression is computed as (X'X)^-1 X'Y.

If X is an (n x k) matrix:

1. (X' X) takes O(n*k^2) time and produces a (k x k) matrix
2. The matrix inversion of a (k x k) matrix takes O(k^3) time
3. (X' Y) takes O(n*k^2) time and produces a (k x k) matrix
4. The final matrix multiplication of two (k x k) matrices takes O(k^3) time

So the Big-O running time is O(k^2*(n + k)).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra

If you get fancy it looks like you can get the time down to O(k^2*(n+k^0.376)) with the Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm.

Comment: The Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm is not practically useable, as the coefficient is so large it requires a matrix so big to begin seeing the benefit of the asymptotic efficiency it is unrealistic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith–Winograd_algorithm

Comment: Hi, I believe that 
3. ```(X'Y)``` takes ```O(mk)```time and produces ```(k x 1)``` matrix

Answer (score 2):

The linear regression is computed as **(X'X)^-1 X'y**.

As far as I learned, **y** is a vector of results (or in other words: dependant variables).

Therefore, if **X** is an (n × m) matrix and **y** is an (n × 1) matrix:

1. The transposing of a (n × m) matrix takes *O(n⋅m)* time and produces a (m × n) matrix
2. **(X' X)** takes *O(n⋅m²)* time and produces a (m × m) matrix
3. The matrix inversion of a (m × m) matrix takes *O(m³)* time
4. **(X' y)** takes *O(n⋅m)* time and produces a (m × 1) matrix
5. The final matrix multiplication of a (m × m) and a (m x 1) matrices takes *O(m²)* time

So the Big-O running time is *O(n⋅m + n⋅m² + m³ + n⋅m + m²)*.

Now, we know that:

- m² ≤ m³
- n⋅m ≤ n⋅m²

so asymptotically, the actual Big-O running time is *O(n⋅m² + m³)* = *O(m²(n + m))*.

And that's what we have from
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra

But, we know that there's a significant difference between the case n → ∞ and m → ∞.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables

So which one should we choose? Obviously it's the number of observations which is more likely to grow, rather than the number of attributes.
So my conclusion is that if we assume that the number of attributes remains constant, we can ignore the m terms and that's a relief because the time complexity of a multivariate linear regression becomes a mere linear *O(n)*. On the other hand, we can expect our computing time explodes by a large value when the number of attributes increase substantially.

Comment: A well reasoned answer, but with a hidden assumption: you assume that the implementation considered is the most efficient solution (which I suspect is in fact likely, but I haven't seen a proof of that).

Answer (score 0):

The linear regression of closed-form model is computed as follow:
derivative of

> RSS(W) = -2H^t (y-HW)

So, we solve for

> -2H^t (y-HW) = 0

Then, the W value is

> W = (H^t H)^-1 H^2 y

where:
**W**: is the vector of expected weights
**H**: is the features matrix N*D where N is the number of observations, and D is the number of features
**y**: is the actual value

Then, the complexity of

> H^t H is n D^2

The complexity of the transpose is D^3

So, The complexity of

> `(H^t H)^-1 is n * D^2 + D^3`

Comment: Isn't that just the complexity of that implementation? Is there any proof that that is the fastest implementation?