# Error in the developing Linear regression model/ R is not responding

Tags: r, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I was in the process of analysis of a dataset related to property sales using r-studio and what I tried to do was develop a model. all was smooth  but this code
`` lm_model <- lm(`SALE PRICE` ~ ., data = trainData) ``
is not working. That means it's not responding nor giving any output.

here is my code

```r
# Check for non-numeric characters
non_numeric <- !grepl("^\\d+$", property_data$`SALE PRICE`)

# Display unique non-numeric values
unique(property_data$`SALE PRICE`[non_numeric])

# Remove non-numeric characters and convert to numeric
property_data$`SALE PRICE` <- as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", property_data$`SALE PRICE`))


# Load necessary libraries
library(caret)
library(glmnet)


# Create dummy variables for categorical features with unique column names
dummy_vars <- dummyVars(~ BOROUGH + `GROSS SQUARE FEET` + `BUILDING CLASS CATEGORY` + `TAX CLASS AT TIME OF SALE`, data = property_data, fullRank = TRUE)
dummy_data <- data.frame(predict(dummy_vars, newdata = property_data)) 

#Prefix the dummy variable column names with a unique identifier
colnames(dummy_data) <- paste("DUMMY_", colnames(dummy_data), sep = "")

# Combine the dummy variables with the original data
property_data <- cbind(property_data, dummy_data)

# Impute missing values in SALE_PRICE with the mean
mean_sale_price <- mean(property_data$`SALE PRICE`, na.rm = TRUE)
property_data$`SALE PRICE`[is.na(property_data$`SALE PRICE`)] <- mean_sale_price


# Split the dataset into training (70%) and testing (30%) sets
set.seed(123)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(property_data$`SALE PRICE`, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
trainData <- property_data[trainIndex, ]
testData <- property_data[-trainIndex, ]
```

upto this it worked.

```r
# Build the regression models
# Simple Linear Regression
lm_model <- lm(`SALE PRICE` ~ ., data = trainData)
```

This one is not giving any respond. The code is still running no response.

I want to develop a regression model to find SALE PRICE. linear regression and lasso-regression will be used

Comment: what are the dimensions of `trainData` ?

Comment: dim(trainData)
 59185    5759

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** I think this is just very slow. In particular, the computational complexity of linear regression [scales with the square of the number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955088/what-is-the-bigo-of-linear-regression). Below are some benchmarks for problems approaching your size (I ran them for varying numbers of rows but you could try to do the same thing for varying numbers of columns ...)

On my machine, for a linear regression the size of your full problem (59K x 5.8K), `lm.fit` took 9 minutes and `fastLm` was actually *slower*, at 16 minutes.

If you do benchmarking with some smaller problems you'll at least be able to project how long you should have to wait for the full problem (i.e., whether it will take 5 or 10 minutes or 5 or 10 days ...)

You *might* gain some speed by setting the whole thing up as a sparse-matrix problem, but that's not trivial AFAICT ...

In this picture (code below), the dotted line represents a curve of the form `time = a*(# rows)^(1.5)`.

Using an algorithm like [gradient descent](https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/0fffa88ae0134d357b09532b26eb4df4) will be **much** slower for small- to medium-sized problems, but might scale better with the number of columns ...

[image]

---

```r
nr <- 59185
nc <- 5759
m <- as.data.frame(y = rnorm(nr),
                   matrix(rnorm(nr*nc), ncol = nc))
f <- function(x) format(object.size(x), units = "Gb")
f(m)  ## 2.5 Gb

X <- as.matrix(m[,-1])
y <- m[,1]

library(RcppEigen) ## for fastLm
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())

rvec <- round(10^(seq(3, log10(nr), length.out = 10)))
nr <- length(rvec)
tmat.lm <- tmat.flm <- matrix(NA, nrow=nr, ncol=3)
for (i in seq_along(rvec)) {
    w <- seq(rvec[i])
    cat(rvec[i],"\n")
    tmat.lm[i,] <- system.time(lm.fit(X[w,], y[w]))[1:3]
    tmat.flm[i,] <- system.time(fastLm(X[w,], y[w]))[1:3]
}

tmat.lm <- tmat.lm[1:nr,]
tmat.flm <- tmat.flm[1:nr,]

f2 <- function(x, lab) {
    colnames(x) <- c("user", "self", "elapsed")
    data.frame(method = lab, size = rvec, x)
}

rr <- (bind_rows(f2(tmat.lm, "lm"), f2(tmat.flm, "flm"))
    |> pivot_longer(-c(method, size), values_to = "time")
    |> filter(name == "elapsed")
)

gg0 <- ggplot(rr, aes(size, time, colour = method)) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    scale_y_log10() +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +
    labs(x = "size (# rows)", y = "time (seconds)")

gg0 +  geom_function(
           colour = "black",
           aes(y = NA),
           data = data.frame(size = unique(rr$size)),
           fun = function(x) 3*(x/1000)^(1.5),
           lty = 2)

ggsave("lm_bench.png")
```